# Unable to install module "hw_scanner" on odoo community10

Tags: odoo-10

I'm planning to use odoo10 community for my small mart but after installed odoo I have to install some mudules to use barcode scanner as I found it in app=>Barcode Scanner Hardware Driver
but after then I get below error

```
Unable to install module "hw_scanner" because an external dependency is not met: No module named evdev
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a python module. You need to install it using pip.

**sudo pip install evdev**